# Shuffle a numpy array with the largest element at the beginning in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to shuffle the array `r1` such that the largest element is always at `r2[0,0]`. The current and one possible expected output is attached.

```
import numpy as np
r1 = np.array([[150.        , 132.5001244 , 115.00024881],
       [ 97.50037321,  80.00049761,  62.50062201],
       [ 45.00074642,  27.50087082,  10.00099522]])
r2=np.random.shuffle(r1)
print("r2 =",r2)
```

The current output is

```
r2 = None
```

One possible expected output is

```
array([[150.,62.50062201,115.00024881],  
       [27.50087082,80.00049761,132.5001244]
       [10.00099522,97.50037321,45.00074642]])
```

Comment: swap the first and largest element once shuffled? And `np.random.shuffle(r1)` shuffles in place, hence why you get `None`.

Comment: Well do it then, what's blocking you?

Comment: ```np.random.shuffle``` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It does, as I said it just works inplace, i.e. it shuffles `r1` directly and returns `None`.

Comment: `shuffle` works fine, but it work in-place and change the original array rather than returning a new one.

Comment: It's not clear why it returns ```None```. If it shuffles ```r1```, it should return some other array which is not the case.

Comment: "it should" no it does exactly what the docs say it's doing, if you want something else it's another issue. If you want another array, make a copy first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For clarity, here is how you should proceed:

```
import numpy as np

r1 = np.array([[150.        , 132.5001244 , 115.00024881],
               [ 97.50037321,  80.00049761,  62.50062201],
               [ 45.00074642,  27.50087082,  10.00099522]])

# make a copy and shuffle the copy
r2 = r1.copy()
np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel())

# get the index of the max
idx = np.unravel_index(r2.argmax(), r2.shape)

# swap first and max
r2[idx], r2[(0, 0)] = r2[(0, 0)], r2[idx]

print(r2)
```

##### Alternative

If the the array is initially sorted, we can use a flat view of the array:

```
r1 = np.array([[150.        , 132.5001244 , 115.00024881],
               [ 97.50037321,  80.00049761,  62.50062201],
               [ 45.00074642,  27.50087082,  10.00099522]])

r2 = r1.copy()

# r2.ravel() returns a view of the original array
# so we can shuffle only the items starting from 1
np.random.shuffle(r2.ravel()[1:])
```

possible output:

```
[[150.          80.00049761  62.50062201]
 [ 97.50037321 132.5001244  115.00024881]
 [ 45.00074642  27.50087082  10.00099522]]
```

Comment: `np.random.shuffle(r2)` will only shuffle the order of rows, not the entire array...

Comment: The outputs are such that when I look across every row, the values are in descending order. I would like to be more random, say it could be descending order in one row, ascending in the other and not in any order in another.